# How to call ajax from anonymous host, header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello i am trying to create a PHP page that can be called by ajax from  anonymous host, I run my code XAMPP host and working nice, But when i try to run it from `http://podserver.info/` means I take a free hosting from there, it is `www.datatwo.podserver.info`. I use the following PHP code

```
<?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization, X-Request-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    echo "hi";
?>
```

and JavaScript ajax code is

```
var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "//www.datatwo.podserver.info/index.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

but it only work when I use XAMPP server and when I upload it to pod server it dos not work, what can I do now?

A error message from console XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.datatwo.podserver.info/index.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: *"it dos not work"* is not enough information to help you. Please read [ask] and provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

When you call ajax podserver don't give you main output from your PHP, server first convert your php to their format you can understand that using browser  `inspect element` you noticed there some extra code added by podserver.